# Expectation of product of brownian motion and stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a deterministic continuous function and $B$ a Brownian motion with $B_0=0$. I need to prove that $$\mathbb{E}\left(B_t\int_0^tf(s)dB_s\right)=\int_0^tf(s)ds.$$ I really am not sure where to start with this. I have considered trying to use limit definition of the stochastic integral by an approximation of $f$ as a simple function, but then I am unsure about taking the limit out of the expectation and if this would even really take me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Compute $d(X_tY_t)$ where $X_t = B_t$ and $Y_t = \int_0^t f(s)dB_s$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - from the hint I ended up with $B_t\int_0^tf(s)dB_s=\int_0^tf(s)ds+\int_0^t(\int_0^sf(u)dB_u+B_sf(s))dB_s$. I presume that taking the expectation then removes the stochastic integral from consideration, but I'm not exactly sure why this is - it is a local martingale, but from as far as I can see not necessarily a true martingale, and so why can we take the expectation as 0?

Comment: @verygoodbloke Since $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on $[0,t]$, which implies $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t ( \int_0^s f(u)dB_s + B_s f(s))^2 ds] < \infty$ for all $t \ge 0$.  This implies the quadratic variation of the stochastic integral has finite expectation, which is a sufficient condition to ensure it's a true martingale.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be that of using Itô's isometry.

Notice that

$$\mathbb E\left[\bigg|\int_0^{\infty} f(s)dB(s)+\int_0^{\infty} g(s)dB(s)\bigg|^2\right]=\mathbb E\left[\bigg|\int_0^{\infty} [f(s)+g(s)] dB(s)\bigg|^2\right]=\int_0^{\infty}[f(s)+g(s)]^2 ds,$$
and this implies that
$$\mathbb E\left[\left(\int_0^{\infty} f(s)dB(s)\right)\left(\int_0^{\infty} g(s)dB(s)\right)\right]=\int_0^{\infty} f(s)g(s)ds.$$

Now notice that $B_t=\int_0^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{[0,t]}(s)dB(s)$ and then the result follows.